# How can I get SQLite to work in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have installed SQLite and am using the wrapper from: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

I have created my database and table in the server explorer in VS2010 but when I create the connection, I don't understand what to do from there and how to get it to work.

Can someone provide code examples on how to connect to a db, get a table, insert data into the table and select data from a table and output it.

I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide what you've done so far so we can advise on where you need to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Explorer is overkill, SQLite is meant to be simple and light. Just use plain code as follows.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=PATH_TO_YOUR_DB;Version=3");
connection.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "insert into something values (1,2,3)";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that did help, but if I replace your example table name "something" with e.g. "Config" and I do have 3 columns. it says the table doesn't exist, am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorted it out, all I did was in server explorer was to point it to the created data source and use that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what I did (assuming that you have that s**t installed):

1.-right click on server explorer

2.-then click on add conection

3.-on data source click `Change` then select sqlite

4.-fill out da details

5.-you are done... you can now add datasets....